# How to output/print value to TextView

Tags: android, kotlin

How to output/print value to TextView correctly?

TextView XML:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/playerOneScore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

function:

```
var PlayerOneScore=12
var score: TextView = findViewById(R.id.playerOneScore) as TextView
score.setText(PlayerOneScore)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of [TextView.setText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) is compatible either with `int` (for android strings) or a `CharSequence` for normal or formatted strings. In your case, you are assigning an `Int` then the first signature is called.

To avoid this, you have to cast the value to `String` to show the value `12` in the textView. This can be achieved as follow:

```
myTextView.setText(myIntValue.toString())
```

take into consideration kotlin provide property access syntax to `getText()/setText()`. Using it you can avoid doing the same mistake.

```
myTextView.text = myIntValue //an error will be displayed because int isn't assignable for CharSequence
myTextView.text = myIntValue.toString() // Good !
```

In your case:

```
score.text = PlayerOneScore.toString()
```

Comment: you shouldn't, where?

Comment: I add it to the "onCreate", and It's working now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

PlayerOneScore.toString()   or   tv.text="$PlayerOneScore"

Answer (score -1):

You're not suppose to use setText iirc.

```
score.text = PlayerOneScore
```

Comment: `you are not suppose` can be confusing, It must be use if you want to assign an R.string